# Replace funcionando só no console log

Tags: javascript

Oi, estou utilizando o REPLACE e ele está funcionando apenas no console.log, e não está alterando o valor na minha página

Esse é o p:

```
<p onmouseover="Substituir()" align="justify" id="textMonika">Monika é notada pelos outros personagens
como inteligente, confiante e atlética. Ela não é tão falante quanto as  outras garotas, mas isso está
implícito para não ser uma escolha. Monika também é conhecida por ser popular, o que faz com que o 
protagonista tenha uma admiração por ela. Ela sempre tem uma expressão calma e gentil e é retratada como
madura e trabalhadora. <br/><br/> Monika já fazia parte do Debate Club, mas foi embora devido a toda a
política e drama internos, destacando o desejo de ordem, liberdade de tópicos e simpatia. O Clube de
Literatura, que ela fundou após deixar o Clube de Debate, é muito importante para ela. Ela aspira a ser
um lugar para mostrar e aumentar a paixão de todos pela literatura.
</p>
```

este o código js:

```
function Substituir(){
    let monika = document.getElementById('textMonika').innerHTML;
    momo = monika.replace("notada", "MONIKA");
    console.log(momo);
}
```

o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da mesma maneira que usas `document.getElementById('textMonika').innerHTML` para ler o conteúdo tens também de repôr o conteúdo. Ou seja, esse valor que tens em `momo` tem de ser reescrito com `document.getElementById('textMonika').innerHTML = momo`.

Uma nota, o replace só substitui a primeira referência, podes usar regex para substituir mais do que uma referência.

```js
function Substituir() {
  let monika = document.getElementById('textMonika');
  momo = monika.innerHTML.replace(/notada/g, "MONIKA");
  monika.innerHTML = momo
}
```

```html
<p onmouseover="Substituir()" align="justify" id="textMonika">Monika é notada pelos outros personagens como inteligente, confiante e atlética. Ela não é tão falante quanto as outras garotas, mas isso está implícito para não ser uma escolha. Monika também é conhecida por ser popular, o que faz com que o protagonista
  tenha uma admiração por ela. Ela sempre tem uma expressão calma e gentil e é retratada como madura e trabalhadora. <br/><br/> Monika já fazia parte do Debate Club, mas foi embora devido a toda a política e drama internos, destacando o desejo de ordem,
  liberdade de tópicos e simpatia. O Clube de Literatura, que ela fundou após deixar o Clube de Debate, é muito importante para ela. Ela aspira a ser um lugar para mostrar e aumentar a paixão de todos pela literatura.
</p>
```